# How to pass value to a 'file' parameter of <include> XML comment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xml-comments

I have a .NET Core web app.

I am using multiple `<include file=...`
tags in comments in my code and I want to store the 'filename' value as a constant and pass it to each of my  tags to get rid of duplication.

```
<include file='filename' path='tagpath[@name="id"]' />
<include file='filename' path='tagpath[@name="id"]' />
```

Example:

```
    /// <include file='Resources/ProjectDescription.xml' path='doc/members/member[@name="SomeTag1"]/*'/>
    public void SomeMethod1()
    {
    }

    /// <include file='Resources/ProjectDescription.xml' path='doc/members/member[@name="SomeTag2"]/*'/>
    public void SomeMethod2()
    {
    }
```

Is there a way to store `'Resources/ProjectDescription.xml'` value as constant and pass it to each include tag?

Comment: `Is there a way to store 'Resources/ProjectDescription.xml' value as constant and pass it to each include tag?` Do you want to dynamically set file attribute for <include> tag?

Comment: @FeiHan It doesn`t need to be changed during runtime, if I understood your question correctly. I just want to store file value in one place instead of every include to be able to easily change it.